# System.QueryException: No such column 'BillingStateCode' on entity 'Account'

Tags: apex, soql, account, compile-error

I have enabled State and Country picklist feature and I am using this query in a web service class:

```
SELECT BillingStateCode FROM Account
```

But I am getting:

> No such column 'BillingStateCode' on entity 'Account'.

I am using `BillingStateCode` and `BillingCountryCode` fields in another class and there it works fine. If I try to execute above query in developer console, there too it works without error. Why does just this one class fail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are getting this error in apex class then I suggest you to update the API Version of your class.

You will get this error if your Apex Class version is less than 27. Update the API version to 27+ and it will compile.